# How do I wire a double stack switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have double stack switch with intention of 2 independent light areas ( undermount cabinet lighting and overhead pot light. When I connect black hot wire to black screw ( both feeds simultaneously connected via pre existing setup with double stacked switch) and black wiring independently connected out to pot light and undermount lighting through separate stacks via brass screws, pot light switches off and on independently- undermount cabinet lighting only switches on when pot light is on. Any suggestions to correct this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A picture would help, along with a wiring diagram and any voltage and continuity tests you've done.

Comment: Look for a tab on one of the sides, that is where you should connect the power that comes in.

Comment: Best practice for understanding switch wiring is to turn the circuit off at the source, then use a continuity tester (or multi-meter set to continuity) to determine where each wire goes. Also, how many cables (with number & color of wires) are coming into each box? Which wires are connected to each other? If possible, map all the relationships with the switch(es) you are using by checking continuity between all the screws with the switches in their different positions. It could be the configuration of connections on the switch is making one light dependent on the other. Post some pics, please.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing which brand you are using, I just googled double stacked switches, saw the [Leviton 5224-2W](http://communities.leviton.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/1922-102-1-2849/Ins%205224%205634.pdf) and noticed the black screws are for the switch legs going to each light while the brass screws are for the hot common, which are typically bridged together with a removable fin (or "tab" as Brad Gilbert mentioned). If the fin has been removed, you will have to create a bridge with wire to feed both switches. When connecting, use the brass screw(s) for the constant hot and the black screws for the independent switch legs. If the connections are mis-arranged on the switch you would have the issue as you describe.

In pictorial form, if you have this:
[image]

You'll need to do this instead:
[image]
The Black and White coming in from the bottom would represent your hot/neutral feed at the switch. This is assuming some things, as your feed could just as well come in at one of the lights. A few pictures from your end would help if this does not look like what you have.